# Salesforce: How do I get a flow to realize that it needs to pull information from the account is referenced in my apex scheduler?

Tags: java, salesforce, apex-code, unhandled-exception, salesforce-flow

I am new to apex and have built an apex schedule class that runs everyday. If an account has an account review date for commissions is two weeks (14 days) away the scheduler will send an email to our Sales Department. The email contains a link to a flow. The flow starts a process to calculate the new commission. To do that, the flow needs to understand to pull information from the account that triggered the email to be sent, the account that has an account review date in 2weeks.

Currently, the email sends out fine with the link to the flow. The link to the flow works, but once you get to the flow, the flow does not know/understand what account it should be pulling information from. I’m not sure if I need to alter my code in my scheduler and/or the code in my flow.

Here is how the flow is accessing information:

Before the first screen, a record lookup in flow occurs. It pulls the information from the account ID and a variable, vaAccountID. I think that the variable {!vaAccountID} is populated with the AccountID that is linked to the commission.

When I run my scheduler, I have it determine if there is an account with an account review date based upon the account Id. It sends the email template with the flow link to the sales department.

The scheduler sends the email and is “happy”. The criteria it needs to execute the method is complete (there is an account with an account review date 14 days from now and it sends the email).

```
global class AccountReviewSchedulerEmailAcc implements Schedulable { 

    global void execute (SchedulableContext ctx) 
    { 
        sendEmail(); 
    }

    public void sendEmail()
    {

        for(Account acc : [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Next_Account_Review_Date__c = : system.Today().addDays(14)])
        {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
            mail.setTemplateId('00XF0000000LfE0'); 
            mail.setTargetObjectId('005J0000000JWYx'); 
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail }); 
        }
    }

}
```

The flow however, is not “happy”. It does not know what account to pull information from.

In the first screen of the flow, it’s supposed to show the recurring revenue and link to the account page. The recurring revenue field is blank. The link to account page does not work.

If I try to advance past the first screen of the flow, I get a generic error screen from Salesforce and a detailed error message from Salesforce. It says:

```
Encountered unhandled fault when running process Organic_Commission_Determination_Flow/301J000000001Tx exception by user/organization: 00DJ00000000YTl/{4} Source organization: 00DA0000000KZI8 (null)
interaction.dal.exception.DALExecutionFault: ; nested exception is: 
    common.exception.ApiQueryException: 
Account.Annual_RR__c FROM Account WHERE (Account.Id = '{!Commission__c.AccountId__c}')
                                         ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:89 invalid ID field: {!Commission__c.AccountId__c} (There was a problem executing your command.) > RETRIEVE

caused by element : Data lookup.Lookup_Account

caused by: interaction.dal.exception.DALExecutionFault: ; nested exception is: 
    common.exception.ApiQueryException: 
Account.Annual_RR__c FROM Account WHERE (Account.Id = '{!Commission__c.AccountId__c}')
                                         ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:89 invalid ID field: {!Commission__c.AccountId__c} (There was a problem executing your command.) > RETRIEVE

Salesforce Error ID: 580775287-15539 (1733087783)
```

What does this error message mean? How can I get more information on Salesforce errors and how to trouble shoot on this matter?
I understand this process is very complex but it relates back to one fundamental question: How do I get the flow to realize that it needs to pull information from the account that had the review date 14 days away in my apex scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SOQL statement that is being executed in the error message:

```
Account.Annual_RR__c FROM Account WHERE (Account.Id = '{!Commission__c.AccountId__c}')
```

This is telling me that the link in your email template is passing the literal value "{!Commission__c.AccountId__c}" into your SOQL, rather than binding the value of that field when sending the email out. So rather than passing an Account Id into the URL, you're passing this string which is most certainly not what the flow is expecting.

This can happen when the API name of the field is entered incorrectly in the email template, or if the record bound to the template isn't of type `Commission__c` as you were expecting. So this could be one of two things: either the record you're sending out isn't of the correct object type for email template `00XF0000000LfE0`, or there is no `AccountId__c` field on the `Commission__c` object.